# Missing assembly binding redirect from StackExchange.Redis 2.0.513 package

Tags: azure, redis, azure-cloud-services, stackexchange.redis

I am getting the following exception when trying to use the latest Nuget package `StackExchange.Redis` in Cloud Service for `.Net 4.7`

> System.InvalidOperationException: The assembly for System.Buffers and System.IO.Pipelines could not be loaded; this usually means a missing assembly binding redirect - try checking this, and adding any that are missing; note that it is not always possible to add this redirects - for example 'azure functions v1'; it looks like you may need to use 'azure functions v2' for that - sorry, but that's out of our control
>      at Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.Helpers.g__Throw|5_0(String msg)
>      at Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.Helpers.AssertDependencies()
>      at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log)
>      at ...

This is coming from a Worker Role in Cloud Service, which is referencing to a class library referencing to this package. Also, I am not able to reproduce this locally. It happens only after deployment to the VM/Cloud Service.

What am I missing?

Comment: see https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/961

Answer (score 2):

Add assembly redirect:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.2.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Found the details [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-buffers-or-one-of-its-dependencies/20380#20380?newreg=621df7fc9a7a4d6e963aeffc6f023df7).

Comment: Running into this issue even after adding a binding redirect. Tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution as well. Am I missing something?